# APIConnect loopback relation

Tags: strongloop, apiconnect

I am trying to create a loopback:relationship using API Connect?  I'm trying to create a simple relationship for two models.  Lets say the first model is Customer and the second model is Order.  I want to create relationship where the Customer has many Orders.  Lets say I create a Customer model with two fields name (string) and age (number) and I create an Order model with two fields description (string) and date (date).  I then run

```
apic loopback:relation
```

to create a Customer  "hasMany" Orders.  I specify the following:

```
Select the model to create the relationship from: Customer
Relation Type :has many 
Choose a model to create a relationship with: Order
Enter the property name for the relation: (orders) ERROR undefined
```

Seems to work fine using the old slc loopback but not in APIC.  Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: I opened a support ticket and they have recreated the error.  They are addressing this issue as a defect.

Comment: It is addressed by updating your apic implementation using npm

Answer (score 1):

This issue was identified as a bug and was fixed by the development team in July of 2016. If you are still having this issue, please update your APIConnect version to a newer version that includes that fix.

As @JT-user2216025 explains above, they were able to solve their issue by updating APIC with NPM.

For instructions on installation and updating the toolkit, please see the following documentation:

[Installing the toolkit](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFS6T/com.ibm.apic.toolkit.doc/tapim_cli_install.html)